# How to read the length and other info of a MKV movie files in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, mkv

Is there a .net library to do this?

Answer (score 2):

There is an example [here](http://www.koders.com/csharp/fid64955C028AF37B54D0E831DD99306B593CE1C8B0.aspx) I think. Its part of the [mkNETtools](http://www.koders.com/info.aspx?c=ProjectInfo&pid=C9ZDH2EH8PETHVBSL4T4NV4H1H).

Downlods should be explained here: http://corp.koders.com/downloads

Comment: Links are long gone.

Answer (score 1):

I recently posted NEbml library sources somewhere on the Net. Google this name. It contains the sample for editing attributes and I'm going to add another sample for reading whole file data.

Answer (score 0):

Do you control the machine (i.e. can you install the Matroska codec on it?) If so, the easiest way might be to load the movie in WPF's video control or another playback framework on Windows and query the length, rather than hardcoding something via the raw container format. More dependencies, but likely useful if you want to go further, like generating thumbnails.

Comment: Thanks. I can't install codecs to the machine, but maybe in the setup. Basically this tool is gonna list the lengths of all movies in a particular directory. So I might have to do this for say 1000 movies.